# Accessing docker containers through IIS

Tags: docker, iis

I have 2 Web API projects (2.1 core) in Visual Studio that I am able to run through Visual Studio and docker CLI.  Both APIs are accessible through the docker host/IP ports (the API at `0.0.0.0:54281->80/tcp` was accessible through `http://localhost:54281`).  However, I am not sure how to configure docker to work with IIS on the container host. Is the solution to configure IIS to use a reverse proxy to the docker host/IP?  I researched configuring IIS within a container but to access the site still required using the IIS docker host/IP.

One of the sites is using a Windows 2008 server and the other is using an Azure Windows 2016 environment.